# How to make derived column in Oracle and then use it?

Tags: oracle10g, derived

How I can make/declare/define a derived column in select query and then use it in where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a column in an SQL query, you can use pretty much any SQL operation that returns a single value (including select statements).  Here are some examples:

```
select 'Y' from dual;
select (5 * 3) cal_col from dual;
select (select min(col1) from table 2) calc_col from dual;
select nvl(col1, 'N') has_value from mytable;
```

From my experience, if you want to use a derived column in a select query, then you must define the column as part of an inner select.  Here is an example:

```
select *
from (
 select (col1 * col2) calc_col
   from mytable
) data
where data.calc_col > 30
```

Another alternative is use the calculation within the where clause itself:

```
select (col1 * col2) calc_col
  from mytable t
 where (col1 * col2) > 30
```

If you are performing a count(*) operation, then you can also leverage the HAVING clause:

```
select field1, count(*)
  from mytable
having count(*) > 3
```

Comment: What is the way if we are getting more than 1 values in it?

Comment: @itsaboutcode The value for a column in a query can only have one value for any given row.  If there are multiple values and you want all of them to be returned, you may need to perform a join with your calculated column data.  Do you have any examples of what you are thinking?